# Linux redirect target IP to other subnet

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have two Linux machines. Both of them have two adapters

```
one frontend -> 172.17.62.x
one backend -> 192.168.141.x
```

I want to make sure that even though two applications are resolving each other's ip using the frontend hostnames, that communication can only happen between these two via the backend adapter. I am NOT allowed to change the /etc/hosts file, so I have to use static routes.

So server A resolves the frontend IP of server B, he shall instead use the backend IP of Server B. If SErver B resolves the frontend IP of Server A, he shall instead use the backend IP of Server B.

I already added a new routing table which uses the standard gateway of the backend network for this purpose

```
OS>echo 200 FRONT_TO_BACK >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
OS>ip route add default via 192.168.141.1 table FRONT_TO_BACK
```

and now I want to add a rule in the format of

```
OS>ip rule add from 172.17.62.188/24 to 172.17.62.194/24 "use device eth1 with source ip 192.168.141.188/24 and to got 192.168.141.194/24" table FRONT_TO_BACK
```

as you can see, I am struggling with formulating what is between the "".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this need source routing (`ip rule`), or would a simple `route add -host $frontend_ip1 gw $backend_ip1` be enough?

Comment: hello ilkkachu. Thank you, it works. I executed the commands and then tested if eth1 (backend ip) is being used via
OS>ip route get <frontend ip>
and
OS>iftop -i eth1